# Auth changes are not reflected laravel 5.3

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and want to make few changes like validation for proper email in login and sending user to login page after logout.

I have made these change in AuthenticatesUsers trait but they do not seems working.

I have changed these functions:

```
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not change `AuthenticatesUsers` trait** . what you can do is override the method in `LoginController`, so copy paste it into your `LoginController`

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

This should work fine.